# How does KnotInfo classify knots based on DT Code?

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory, knot-invariants

The site [KnotInfo](https://knotinfo.math.indiana.edu/homelinks/knotfinder.php) can classify many small knots up to mirroring given a Dowker–Thistlethwaite Code of the knot, and can even identify whether a knot is a connected sum of other small knots.

Being very inexperienced in knot theory, I don't understand how exactly it does this. I had thought there might be a way to manipulate the DT code in a way reminiscent of Reidemeister moves in order to simplify the diagram, but I haven't been able to find any online resources that suggest how this might be done.

In particular I'd appreciate an explanation of the algorithm, and/or a link to a resource describing it.

Thanks

Comment: That's using [Knotscape](http://pzacad.pitzer.edu/~jhoste/hostewebpages/kntscp.html), which computes invariants of the knot (like the HOMFLY polynomial) and looks up possibilities in pre-computed knot tables. I'm not sure exactly everything it does, though.